# trivial deformation of a smooth affine scheme over complete DVR

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a affine smooth scheme finite type over $A/pA$, where $A$ a complete DVR and $chk=p>0$.

I know that since $H^{2}=0=H^{1}$, we have a unique lifting to $A/p^{2}$. In algebraic schemes case, we can obtain a trivial deformation by fiber product. But in this case, for example, $A$ is a p-adic number ring, What is the trivial deformation over $A/p^{2}$ ?

PS: I added some smooth conditions to $X$.

Comment: There might not exist a lifting of $X$ to $A/p^2$, let alone a canonical one.

Comment: I'm confused Angelo. The question says $X$ is affine and the obstruction to such a lifting lies in $H^2$ which vanishes, so doesn't such a lift always exist?

Comment: @Matt:  Assuming the scheme is finite type over $k$, the obstruction most naturally lives in an Ext group of the cotangent complex.  If $X$ is smooth, this reduces to $H^2$, which will be zero as you say.  However, this need not be the case if $X$ is singular.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I've clearly been indoctrinated by only thinking about liftability of smooth varieties.